# How to generate a static snapshot of a page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, static, heroku

I have a rails app that generates a webpage with some reports (Google charts backed by Postgres). The reports are quite time consuming to generate and don't change during the day. I would like to schedule the generation of this page at a certain time of the day and then just serve this static page during the day? What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: why not use page caching or, if necessary, fragment caching?
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html or for rails 2.3 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/caching_with_rails.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`caches_page` is what you're looking for:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching

You can add Memcached etc into this mix too if needs be based on the type of infrastructure you're running.